# Принудительно открыть окно команд NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, параметры, argv

Я запускаю node js из C# кода, используя класс Procces

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node run.js";
```

Конкректные скрипты запускает и все работает отлично. Но как принудительно открыть такое окно? Может быть есть какой-нибудь параметр?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В параметрах запуска консоли нужно указать /k вместо /c  Тогда после выполнения команды консоль не закрывается.

Comment: Что означает слово "принудительно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется REPL, Read-Eval-Print-Loop.Если stdin подключен не к консоли, то чтобы принудительно открыть REPL используйте ключ

```
cmd /c node -i
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script